rust clap default_values_t for a vector, where flag may repeat and may not
    #[clap(long = "type", num_args = 0.., default_values_t = [MyType::a], value_parser = MyType::from_string)]
    pub name_types: Vec<MyType>,

    #[clap(long = "name", num_args = 1..)]
    pub names: Vec<String> 

I have a similar code (MyType is a enum with two possible values, assume "a" and "b"). I can call my cli:
my-cli --name andrew --type a --name billy --type b and it will create names as ["andrew","billy"] and name_types as [MyType::a, MyType::b]. But I wanna call it as  my-cli --name andrew --name billy --type b and expect it to work as well (default value for type, if it's not preset to be MyType::a). Also, i want it to keep the order, i.e. if i call cli as my-cli --name andrew  --name billy --type b --name carol => name_types = [a,b,a]

From what I can tell, you are implicitly expecting a 1-to-1 relation between the elements of names and of name_types. Well, you haven't told clap about it, nor is clap suitable for specifying this kind of non-trivial logical relations - that's not the job of a command line parser.
Instead, probably the best way to do this is to keep your clap stuff simple. Then write custom logic to "post-process" clap's output into a structure that properly encodes the logical relation, and use that in your core application.
Here's what I would write. Bear in mind I personally prefer a declarative and functional style, but this could be just as well written imperatively.
use clap::{CommandFactory, FromArgMatches, Parser, ValueEnum};

// ValueEnum is probably the better way to do this
// unless your type is actually more complicated than in this example
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, ValueEnum)]
enum MyType {
    A,
    B,
}

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
struct Cli {
    // #[clap(...)] is deprecated
    #[arg(long = "type")]
    pub name_types: Vec<MyType>,

    // num_args doesn't do what you probably think it does
    // see https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/issues/4507#issuecomment-1372250231
    #[arg(long = "name", required = true)]
    pub names: Vec<String>,
}

// this type properly expresses the logical relation
// "each name must have an associated type"
#[derive(Debug)]
struct User {
    name: String,
    name_type: MyType,
}

fn main() {
    let matches = Cli::command().get_matches();
    let Cli { name_types, names } = Cli::from_arg_matches(&matches).unwrap();

    // get the applicable index range of the `--type` option for each name
    // the `--type` options found between a `--name` and the next is applicable
    let applicable_type_index_ranges = {
        // get indices of `names`
        let mut name_indices = matches
            .indices_of("names")
            .into_iter()
            .flatten()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        // for the last `--name` option, the upper index is unbounded
        name_indices.push(std::usize::MAX);
        name_indices
            .windows(2)
            .map(|window| match window {
                [start, end] => (*start, *end),
                _ => unreachable!(),
            })
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
    };
    assert_eq!(names.len(), applicable_type_index_ranges.len());

    // pair the `--type` options with their indices
    let name_types_with_indices = {
        let type_indices = matches
            .indices_of("name_types")
            .into_iter()
            .flatten()
            .collect::<Vec<_>>();
        assert_eq!(name_types.len(), type_indices.len());
        name_types.into_iter().zip(type_indices).collect::<Vec<_>>()
    };

    // construct `User`s with types properly assigned
    let users = names
        .into_iter()
        .zip(applicable_type_index_ranges)
        .map(|(name, (start_idx, end_idx))| {
            let name_type = name_types_with_indices
                .iter()
                // only `--type` options within the range are applicable
                .filter_map(|&(t, idx)| (idx > start_idx && idx < end_idx).then_some(t))
                // assuming you want the last applicable `--type` to take precedence
                .last()
                // your default value if no `--type` is present
                .unwrap_or(MyType::A);
            User { name, name_type }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    dbg!(users);
}

$ cargo run -- --name romeo --type b --name juliett
[src/main.rs:86:5] users = [
    User {
        name: "romeo",
        name_type: B,
    },
    User {
        name: "juliett",
        name_type: A,
    },
]

As you can see, it can be done but it's non-trivial, with plenty of places where it would be weird for clap to make an opinionated design decision for you.

Thank you very much for such a broad answer. I ended up pointing out that if the number of specified types != the number of names then an error is generated (quick fix), but I will revise what I wrote and try to redo it according to your code. I searched a lot for some information on different clap arguments, but didn't find the right one (I knew I should do some parser or something like that, but didn't know how).
